# How am I suppose to find the area between the given curves (2 seperate, based on same, areas)

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Could do I find the area inside the curve which bounds the area, curve is $$1.\ \ \ \ \ (y-\arcsin x)^2=x-x^2$$
$$2.\ \ \ \ x=\frac {1-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}, y= \frac {2at}{(1+t^2)^2}$$

I was traditionally taught to draw the figures, then see what functions I have to integrate. Keep in mind, this must be done with single integrals, I assume maybe that I have to use some question some of the characteristics of the function, because drawing it would be very difficult. These are two seperate graphs. I assume there done similarly. Any ideas, thoughts?

Comment: Hint for the first one: Solve for y and subtract the two solution curves from each other.

Comment: these are two sepreate questions

Comment: 1. Find the area of the figure bounded by the curve $(y-\arcsin x)^2=x-x^2$

Comment: I see that. I was giving you a hint for solving the first of the two questions.

Comment: Can you maybe type out how to solve the curve?

Comment: I honestly dont know

Comment: I updated my answer. Not sure if that helps you but I tried my best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial Answer/Hint for the first one:

$$\left(y-\arcsin{x}\right)^2=x-x^2 |^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
\pm\left(y-\arcsin{x}\right)=\sqrt{x-x^2}|\pm\arcsin{x}\\
\pm y = \sqrt{x-x^2}\pm\arcsin{x}|\cdot\pm 1\\
y=\pm\sqrt{x-x^2}+\arcsin{x}$$
Now you have two solutions:

$$ y_1 = \sqrt{x-x^2}+\arcsin{x}\\
y_2 = -\sqrt{x-x^2}+\arcsin{x}$$

Now calculate $y_1 - y_2$ and integrate the result where it is real.

Hint for the second one:

The general formula for integrating a parametric equation like this is:

$$\int_a^b y(t) \, x'(t) \, dt$$

In your case, $t \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. you gotta integrate over the whole real line.

First, substitute $t \to \tan{\theta}$:

$$dt=\frac{d\theta}{\cos^2{\theta}}\\
\frac{dx}{dt} \frac{dt}{d\theta}=2 \sin (\theta ) \cos^5(\theta ) \left(\tan^2(\theta )-3\right)\\
y \to 2 a \sin (\theta) \cos ^3(\theta)$$

and the new limits are $\mp\frac{\pi}{2}$

With this information your formula becomes:

$$4a\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\frac{-\pi}{2} \sin ^2(\theta ) \cos
   ^6(\theta ) \left(\tan
   ^2(\theta )-3\right) d\theta$$

After a long series of trigonometric manipulations you eventually arrive at this integral being

$$4a\int \sin ^2(\theta ) \cos^6(\theta ) \left(\tan^2(\theta )-3\right) d\theta= -\frac{1}{64} a (24 \theta +12 \sin (2 \theta )-4 \sin (4 \theta )-4 \sin (6\theta )-\sin(8 \theta ))$$

If you plug in your range you finally arrive at the desired answer:
$$4a\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\frac{-\pi}{2} \sin ^2(\theta ) \cos
   ^6(\theta ) \left(\tan
   ^2(\theta )-3\right) d\theta=\frac{3 \pi  a}{8}$$

For those trigonometric manipulations (see below) you should recall that: $$1=\cos^2{\theta}+\sin^2{\theta}\\e^{i\theta}=\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}\\ \tan{\theta}=\frac{\sin{\theta}}{\cos{\theta}}$$
With those you can slowly but surely reduce the above integral to a form where you can arrive at the solution.

I am almost certain there is a faster way than this though: It's quite a pain and long. I would be surprised if that's how it's supposed to be done. I can't see said simpler way right now though.

---

As per request, here are the necessary further manipulations: First, replace $\tan$ with $\frac{\sin}{\cos}$ and find the common denominator:
$$3-\tan^2\theta=\frac{3\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}$$
Then replace $\sin^2 \to 1-\cos^2$:

$$\frac{3\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}=\frac{3\cos^2\theta-(1-\cos^2\theta)}{\cos^2\theta}=\frac{4\cos^2\theta-1}{\cos^2\theta}$$

This you can plug into the original integrand and cancel out the fraction:

$$4 a \sin ^2(\theta ) \cos^6(\theta ) \left(\tan^2(\theta )-3\right)=4 a \sin ^2(\theta ) \cos^6(\theta ) \frac{4\cos^2\theta-1}{\cos^2\theta}=\\
4 a \sin ^2(\theta )\cos^4\theta\left(4\cos^2\theta-1\right)$$

Here you can now use Euler's Formula to get $$\cos\theta=\frac{e^{i \theta}+e^{-i \theta}}{2}\\
\sin\theta=\frac{e^{i \theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2 i}$$ and, applying this everywhere,

$$-\frac{1}{64} \left(e^{-i\theta }-e^{i \theta}\right)^2 \left(e^{-i\theta }+e^{i \theta}\right)^4\left(-1+\left(e^{-i \theta}+e^{i \theta}\right)^2\right)$$

Expanding this gives

$$\frac{3}{64} e^{-2 i \theta
   }+\frac{3}{64} e^{2 i
   \theta }-\frac{1}{32} e^{-4
   i \theta }-\frac{1}{32}
   e^{4 i \theta
   }-\frac{3}{64} e^{-6 i
   \theta }-\frac{3}{64} e^{6
   i \theta }-\frac{1}{64}
   e^{-8 i \theta
   }-\frac{1}{64} e^{8 i
   \theta }+\frac{3}{32}$$

and, after reducing this to sines and cosines again,

$$\frac{3}{32} \cos (2 \theta
   )-\frac{1}{16} \cos (4
   \theta )-\frac{3}{32} \cos
   (6 \theta )-\frac{1}{32}
   \cos (8 \theta
   )+\frac{3}{32}$$

This can finally easily be integrated and gives

$$\frac{3 \theta
   }{32}+\frac{3}{64} \sin (2
   \theta )-\frac{1}{64} \sin
   (4 \theta )-\frac{1}{64}
   \sin (6 \theta
   )-\frac{1}{256} \sin (8
   \theta )$$

Putting in the limits $\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$ yields $\frac{3\pi}{32}$. We are now only missing the factor $4 a$. Multiply it to the result and you are done.

---

A minor last warning: I think I made a sign error somewhere in there. I'll correct it later if I find it (or perhaps somebody else finds it) but the end result should be positive for $a>0$ which it is in my later solution but it's not in my earlier one (which prompted me to switch the integration order so the result would become negative but that may not have been necessary after all)
Anyway I'm pretty confident that the last addition is correct. Hopefully this is enough for you. Any further step is just direct manipulation of binomials. You should very much be able to do those on your own.

Comment: Could you solve the integral, with this good work here?

Comment: This ought to be enough detail now.

Comment: Very precise, I tip my hat off to you kind sir.. :)

Comment: you cant really root in the begining

Comment: because what if x=2, then you have a square root of a negative number

Comment: hence : $x-x^2$=-2

Comment: I told you, integrate where it is real. Hint: Try what happens at $x=\frac{1}{2}$, x=1 or x=0

Comment: (Besides, arcsin isn't defined everywhere in the reals either so that also constraints your range)

Comment: how did you find $dx \over dt$ ?

Comment: by doing just that. Differentiate. x(t) with respect to t using all your favorite differentiation rules like the chain rule, the product rule or the quotient rule. If you are tasked with integration, differentiation should be well within your abilities.

Comment: I can't see what x(t) is , is what im saying:)

Comment: x(t) should be a function of t i presume, I just cannot pinpoint it here..

Comment: it's what you were given right away. You wrote it yourself in your question. x and y (with respect to t) are given.

Comment: That is a completely different independant question on its own

Comment: Well for the first one you don't have a x(t). My answer answers both of your questions now. For the first one that is completely unnecessary. Your function isn't given parametric in t, it's given implicitly in two variables x and y

Comment: How would these two be solved seperately? i opened a new question for the second

Comment: They ARE solved separately. I answered both your questions. The solution for the first one stops before "Hint for the second one:" - read

Comment: I see now, I apologize..